# Requests different between post auth like data and and get auth like parameter

Tags: python, authentication, post, get, request

I'm studying something about requests and i encountered a problem.
Which is different between this requests: (Ignor URL, it's just example)

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=("Superuser", "SuperSecretPassword"))
```

and this:

```
login_form = {"username" : "Superuser", "password" : "SuperSecretPassword"}
requests.post('https://api.github.com/user', data = login_form)
```

I'm begginer, so I'm little bit overhealmed, Thanks in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of authentication where every backend supports a different kind of authentication.

Requests module has some inbuilt authentication mechanisms which are widely used by the developers.
Ref: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/

Now `auth` parameter will do some computation with the given value and pass that as a header to the backend
but when you pass data in a post request it will be passed as POST request parameters to the backend.

If you see the basic authentication in the above reference you will observe that it is a shorthand for HTTPBasicAuth